# how to add subject alternative name in existing x.509 certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have one certificate which has "RFC822 Name=null" in "subject alternative name".
Can I know how can we edit this extension so that I can put some value in this field.

Comment: You would need to generate new certificate and specify the value of SubjectAltName during generation.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp it seems, that your comment is only correct answer...